# Pause script for manual event

Tags: r

I have a script that I want to pause to allow external error checking.  At one point the script writes out a .csv file that I need to manually check externally and then re-import before moving on.  Is there a way to tell R to pause the script after the after the `write.cv` command?

```
write.csv(x,"file.csv", row.names = FALSE) #export raw .csv file

##### pause to manually check for and correct errors ####

y <- read.csv("file.csv") #import corrected "file.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `readline()` function for an interactive input. Your code snippet could look like this:

```
write.csv(x,"file.csv", row.names = FALSE) #export raw .csv file
cat("Output written to file \"file.csv\".\n")
readline("Please hit \"enter\" to continue.") #script paused 
y <- read.csv("file.csv") #import corrected "file.csv"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: odd, that doesn't seem to work. I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1103. When I run the code, it blazes right through. Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and can't figure out how to get the following to show as a code block in a comment:

`write.csv(merg2,"file.csv", row.names = FALSE)

cat("Manually check \"file.csv\" file for errors in PSU or depth. \n")

Manually check "file.csv" file for errors in PSU or depth.

readline("Please hit \"enter\" to continue.")

Please hit "enter" to continue.

[1] ""

driftPSUinfo <- read.csv("file.csv")`

Comment: @Ben Sorry to hear that it doesn't work. I can't confirm this on my system, where it works as expected. I don't know what could be the reason for your problem. Does this minimal script work: `cat (10:1,"\n"); cat("Now we're taking a break.\n");  readline("Please hit \"enter\" to continue."); cat(1:10,"\nDone.\n")`?

Comment: I can only guess that on some older systems the input provided by `readline()` has to be assigned to a variable. It could be worth trying `dummy <- readline("Please hit \"enter\" to continue.")`. The result should be the same.